# How do I get Skype 4.0 to open multiple chat windows?

Tags: skype

Since Skype 4.0 I'm not able to open more than one chat window. If I want to chat with more than one person I have to close person one's chat window and open one with person two. Even if I click on person two's entry in the contact list and click on "chat" the window of person one will be replaced with person two's chat window.

I suspect there is an option in the preferences o change this obnoxious behavior but I can't seem to find it.

So how do I have Skype 4.0 open a separate chat window every person without replacing the old one?

Again this problem is new in 4.0, i.e. 2.0 Beta didn't have that problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the [Skype Support Center](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA2711/how-can-i-see-several-conversations-next-to-each-other):

> It’s possible to show instant message conversations in separate windows. To do so:
>
> - Sign in to Skype.
> - In the menu bar, click View.
> - Select Compact View.

For older versions read below this line.

---

Alright after extensive trying I found out.

1. **Click the Skype Icon** on the bottom left of the main Window
2. In the Menu select "**Options**"
3. In the resulting Window select "**Chat**" on the left
4. Then uncheck the checkbox to the left of "**User Default View**"

[image: Skype Options]
[image: Enable multiple Chat Windows]

Comment: This no longer seems to work on Linux/Ubuntu 12.04 (The option does not exist.)

Comment: The menu item is now named 'IM'.

Answer (score 2):

On the current version of Skype, on Windows, we have this option View > Compact.

https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA2711/how-can-i-see-several-conversations-next-to-each-other

I'm thinking in the current version of Skype that option may also be available on Ubuntu, but I don't have a system at hand to test it...

Answer (score 1):

Right click on each contact you want to have in a separate window, "Pop-out chat".

Comment: I don't think I have this option.

Comment: I have 4.0.0.7 on Ubuntu e I can confirm the option is there.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to edit your answer with a screenshot. That'd be nice.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. My print screen key doesn't work in that window. Moreover my language is Italian, so I don't have exactly that option.

Comment: However, you can reproduce clicking on the skype indicator icon on Unity panel, then click on recent chat, then right click on one of your recent contacts.

Comment: I'm positive now, that I don't have that option. This is really weird.